# GCE VM taken down randomly and re-inserted

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have a single GCE VM running behind an http load balancer. Its too early to have multiple VMs, saving money.

What happens is this VM seems to be deleted and reinserted randomly by GCE. My tiny web app dies for that duration. I see these in my VM logs:

```
compute.instances.delete
compute.instances.insert
```

Seems like GCE maintenance activity. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Plain / normal GCE instances will not be deleted / inserted on their own. The only places this can happen is with the relevant managed compute options, like instance groups / autoscaling / preemptibles / ...

Comment: @mensi thats right, this is in a managed instance group which has a backend service which the load balancer uses. Any clues on preventing this from happening? I have autoscaling turned off.

Comment: That sounds like you probably also have health checking set up -> did you by any chance enable auto-healing? If so, instances would be recreated if they fail health checks

Comment: I have health check setup indeed. But cant figure out why it would fail. Because if it is failing, recreating the vm be the right thing to do I guess. thanks for the hint though, will look this one up and post back if I discover anything worthwhile sharing.